# How to analyse stack trace of the exceptions which comes in the case of crashes in android

Tags: android, exception, crash

I am using crittercism tool to get crash reports.I receive mails when there is a crash but I am not getting the meaning of the stack trace which shows the logs for the crashes.
for eg :

```
0       java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
1   at  java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:607)
2   at  com.webaroo.replyall.utils.ah.d(Unknown Source)
3   at  com.webaroo.replyall.utils.ah.b(Unknown Source)
4   at  com.webaroo.privatechat.ui.f.getView(Unknown Source)
5   at  android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1448)
6   at  android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1786)
7   at  android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1325)
8   at  android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1617)
9   at  com.webaroo.replyall.controls.CustomListView.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
10  at  android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1299)
11  at  com.webaroo.replyall.controls.CustomListView.onLayout(Unknown Source)
12  at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
13  at  android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:943)
14  at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
15  at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
16  at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
17  at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
18  at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
19  at  android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1189)
20  at  android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1914)
21  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
22  at  android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
23  at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3833)
24  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
25  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
26  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
27  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
28  at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the above logs I am not able to get which of the above line is exactly causing crash or throwing the exception.What exactly all those lines points at?Also what written in the brackets()  at the end of each line means?

Answer (score 0):

Scan the trace up to down and try to see something you recognize as your code. In this case it seems `android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView` throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` at line `1448`.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is "ConcurrentModificationException" which means there is two or more threads trying to use an ArrayList.... your code is obfuscated, but it seems like an error at a ListAdapter.

The written in "brackets()" are the source:codeLine ... but "Unknown Source" means he can't specify or found the source, maybe cause obfuscation you used.

Answer (score 0):

Trace it line by line and you will see what class of your application has a problem and with the line number where the crash actually occurs.